# How to find if an image has a caption on it using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Many different sites have captions on images in paragraphs, h1 tags or   mapped inside a div with image.

I want to know how to find if an image has a caption associated with it using Javascript specially when the caption is placed on the image and occupying space.

Examples below differ so is there any single way to find caption or not.

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/small_island_wallpaper_beaches_nature_wallpaper_1388.jpg" alt="Tea cup with steam and pen on bed">
  <figcaption>Journaling with Tea</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/small_island_wallpaper_beaches_nature_wallpaper_1388.jpg" alt="Tea cup with steam and pen on bed">
  <p>Journaling with Tea</p>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
 <head>
  <style type="text/css"> 
  .imageHolder {
      position: relative;
      width: 285px;
      height: 175px;
  }
  .imageHolder .caption {
      position: absolute;
      width: 283px;
      height: 50px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      color: #ffffff;
      background: green;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      opacity: 0.7;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="imageHolder">
   <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/small_island_wallpaper_beaches_nature_wallpaper_1388.jpg" alt="" />
   <div class="caption">
    <br>Caption goes here
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could use the bounding client rectangle of any of the images sibling elements to see if they are overlapping or directly adjacent to the image

Comment: From the second example there's no way to detect if the text is meant to be a caption or not.

Comment: @Juhana:  But that's how it is on site http://www.firstpost.com/sports/india-vs-west-indies-difference-in-fielding-marks-gulf-between-both-teams-2919910.html. First image.

Comment: the only thing in common with all these examples is that the caption consists of the text within the next element after the `<img` tag. So if you have jQuery you could use the .next() function to get the next element along. https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: @ADyson: With all due respect my company is adtech and I need to use pure javascript for many reasons.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference which site it's on. That markup still contains zero information about whether it's a caption or "normal" text.

Comment: @MiHawk ok well maybe you can work out from the jQuery source code how they do it and re-implement!

Comment: Juhana and ADyson : Ok. Thank you.

Comment: @ADyson ... the jQuery .next() function is not black magic ... it would be using `element.nextElementSibling` - no need for jQuery bloat for such a simple task

Comment: @Juhana - using bounding client rectangle of the image and the text, you can determine that the text is immediately below the image - using some intelligence, you can determine with high accuracy the probability that it is or isn't a caption

Comment: @JaromandaX I realise it's all based on pure JS in the end, but not having researched it I didn't know what it would be using underneath - sometimes there's a direct JS equivalent method, other times they implement extra features. I tend to use jQuery for everything, for convenience and consistency. If I'd needed to know myself, I'd have looked it up as well - hence my suggestion to the OP. Since you already know, you may have saved them (and me) some time - so thanks for the tip

Comment: @ADyson - I know my response may have seemed a little aggressive, but it wasn't meant to be

Comment: @JaromandaX don't worry I didn't think it was, just wanted to clarify why I suggested jQuery :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the format is always like this:

```
<div class="imageHolder">
        <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/small_island_wallpaper_beaches_nature_wallpaper_1388.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
            <br>Caption goes here
        </div>
    </div>
```

maybe something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imageHolder");
    var c=x[0].childNodes;
    return (c[3].className=="caption");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this example:

```
 <div class="image" id="theImage">   <img
 src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/small_island_wallpaper_beaches_nature_wallpaper_1388.jpg"
 alt="Tea cup with steam and pen on bed">   <p>Journaling with Tea</p>
 </div>
```

So if you know ho is designed the caption you can extract it easy with parents and children DOM model.

```
//get the div/div's
var div = document.getElementById("theImage");
var children = div .children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var chield= children[i];
  // Do stuff
  // You can get if is image by className
  // if is p then get innerTEXT
}
```